# How to set a zoom level as 15 in the MapKit using iPhone sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am implementing a MapKit based application. In that I need to set the zoom level as 15. Based on this I need to change the region. I tried with the following code but it is not working as expected. When I used the returned region and set to the Mapview it is getting exception like "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region '".Can you guys suggest perfect way to solve this problem?

```
-(MKCoordinateRegion)getRegoinBasedOntheZoomLevel:(int)zoom
```

{

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;  

if (coords1.latitude != 0 && coords1.longitude !=0) 
{
    region.center = coords1;
}
else 
{
    region.center=mainMapView.region.center;
}
span.latitudeDelta=mainMapView.region.span.latitudeDelta *2*zoom;
span.longitudeDelta=mainMapView.region.span.longitudeDelta *2*zoom;
region.span=span;
return region;
```

}

Thanks in advance.
Sekhar Bethalam.

Answer (score 2):

Sekhar, I'm not really sure what your code is trying to achieve - it is multiplying an (unspecified) span by 2*zoom: I'm pretty sure it is not going to do what you say. 'zoom' is generally defined as a number n between 0 and N where 2^n is the number of map tiles around the earth.

Rather than try to explain the theory, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166444/mkmapview-zoom-and-region) I found (by searching this forum) that provides an excellent overview, including hyperlinks to an excellent description of the theory and practice of Mercator projections, map tiles, and even the [actual MKMapView code you need](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/).