# MKMapView userLocation, right position, wrong coord?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I am writing a test application with an MKMapView that appears when the application starts, right at the start I want to initialise the mapView to be more appropriate to where the user is so I am using `userLocation` to get the the "users current location"

```
MKUserLocation *currentLocation = [[self mMapView] userLocation];
[[self mapView] setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

This works fine and puts a pin in the correct place (all be it that the map is zoomed way out) I have two problems:

**PROBLEM:(1)**

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([[currentLocation location] coordinate], 200, 200);
[[self mapView] setRegion:region];
```

Even though the annotation pin is in the correct place (i.e. iOS clearly knows where I am) when I try and query the location coordinate I just get [0.0000] and [0.0000]

**PROBLEM:(2)**

When I zoom or pan the map the pin drops again, so each time you move you get a new pin drop animation. Is there a way to stop this?

**NOTE:** *I am using CLLocationManager later in my code, this was just something I was trying quickly when the application first loads to give the user a better feeling for where they were rather than just looking at the default zoomed out google map.*

Comment: You can find a simalar topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166444/mkmapview-zoom-and-region).

Comment: Thank you but my question is not about calculating a region using spans and deltas, I am using MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance which only requires a centre long/lat coordinate and a zoom distance in meters.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for prob 1.
Hey it works fine at the Device ..... In simulator it will show you as (0,0)