# determine current zoomscale for mapview

Tags: ios, zooming, android-mapview

How can I calculate the current zoomScale for an MKMapView?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166444/mkmapview-zoom-and-region - may be it will help

Comment: I am actually using TroyBrant's MKMapView category to get the zoomLevel, but I also need zoomScale.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
#define MERCATOR_RADIUS 85445659.44705395
#define MAX_GOOGLE_LEVELS 20

- (double)getZoomLevel {
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta;
    CGFloat mapWidthInPixels = self.mapView.bounds.size.width;
    double zoomScale = longitudeDelta * MERCATOR_RADIUS * M_PI / (180.0 * mapWidthInPixels);
    double zoomer = MAX_GOOGLE_LEVELS - log2( zoomScale );
    if ( zoomer < 0 ) zoomer = 0;
    //  zoomer = round(zoomer);
    return zoomer;
}
```

The return value of the `getZoomLevel` method will be the current zoom level of your `mapView` property.