# Convert Zoom Level to Region Span

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview, zooming

I figured out how to calculate the current zoom level of the map from
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/ (the first comment on that blog), but it gives me a value between 0 and 20, whereas `region.span` has values like `0.1f, 0.01f` etc.

I want to calculate the current zoom level and then if a user does a "long tap", then an annotation has to be dropped. I have done everything except that I have hardcoded following:

```
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.2f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.2f;
```

So instead of `0.2f`, I would like to put a number which I get from Zoom Level (between 0-20). So is there any way to do this conversion?

Is it done like this?

```
(Current Zoom Level Output/Maximum Zoom Level);
```

Comment: longtitudeDelta is not a fraction of the total zoom amount. It is the number of degrees for latitude you can see from the far left of the view to the far right. Delta = difference between the two sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled your exact question and the second result was pointing back to StackOverflow here: [MKMapView Zoom and Region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166444/mkmapview-zoom-and-region) which has a very well detailed answer. The short version is: try using [mapview region].span.latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta.

ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/region
and:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html