# Zoom in further than google map max zoom.

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, mkmapview

Im making a `MKMapView` with an `overlay` and im not really using the map for anything else than the `coordinates` so dont need to see the roads or what not.

The problem that im running into is that my `overlay` is in a small geographical area so it stops me zooming in far enough to see the `overlay` properly.

Is there a away to go past this zoom limit?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to increment programmatically the **latitudeDelta** and **longitudeDelta** of the *region span* attribute?

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1 = { region_x, region_y };
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta = 1, .longitudeDelta = 1};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord1, span};
[_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

For details: [MKMapView Zoom and Region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166444/mkmapview-zoom-and-region)

Comment: Ask if you need more help!